# Improper integral about exp appeared in Titchmarsh's book on the zeta function

Tags: special-functions, improper-integrals, riemann-zeta

May I ask how to do the following integration?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(\pi n^{2}/x) -(\pi t^2 x)}}{\sqrt{x}} dx $$

where $t>0$, $n$ a positive integer.

This came up on page 32 ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7FAo.png)) of Titchmarsh's book, [*The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=1CyfApMt8JYC&pg=PA32). Specifically for the sum involving $b_n$, I am wondering how to

> multiply by $e^{-\pi t^{2} x}$ and integrate over $(0,\infty)$

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I added an image of the relevant page and rephrased your question slightly. Please feel free to make any changes you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, this looks great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\, \exp\left(-\frac{\pi n^2}{x} - \pi t^2 x\right)
&=& 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{t}} \int_0^\infty dz\, \exp\left(-\pi n t(z^2 + z^{-2})\right)
    \hspace{5ex} (\textrm{let } x=z^2 n/t) \\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{n}{t}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ds\, e^{s/2}
    \exp\left(-2 \pi n t \cosh s\right)
    \hspace{5ex} (\textrm{let } z=e^{s/2}) \\
&=& 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{t}} \int_0^\infty ds\, \cosh\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) 
    \exp\left(-2 \pi n t \cosh s\right) \\
&=& 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{t}} K_{\frac{1}{2}} (2\pi n t)
    \hspace{5ex} (\textrm{modified Bessel function, 2nd kind}) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-2\pi n t}}{t}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

*Addendum*: An approach not involving special functions.
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\, 
    \exp\left(-\frac{\pi n^2}{x} - \pi t^2 x\right)
&=& 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{t}} \int_0^\infty dz\, 
    \exp\left(-\pi n t(z^2 + z^{-2})\right) 
    \hspace{5ex} (\textrm{as before}) \\
&=& 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{t}} \int_0^\infty dz\, 
    \exp\left(-\pi n t(z-z^{-1})^2 - 2\pi n t\right) \\
&=& \sqrt{\frac{n}{t}}  e^{-2\pi n t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty du\,
    \left(1+\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+4}}\right) e^{-\pi n t u^2} 
    \hspace{4ex} (z-z^{-1}=u) \\
&=& \frac{e^{-2\pi n t}}{t} 
    \hspace{5ex} (\textrm{odd integral vanishes; Gaussian left over}) 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Nice work here !(+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Cheers!